# If $a>0$ and $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)+1=(ax^2+bx+c)^2$, then find the value of $a+b+c$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

> **Q3/30** If $a>0$ and $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)+1=(ax^2+bx+c)^2$, then find the value of $a+b+c$.

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you tried setting $x=1,$ then you'd have all you want.

Answer (score 5):

$\begin{split}
(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)+1  & =[(x+1)(x+4)][(x+2)(x+3)]+1\\
&=[(x^2+5x+5)-1][(x^2+5x+5)+1]+1\\
&=(x^2+5x+5)^2\end{split}$

$\therefore$The answer equals $1+5+5=11$

Comment: why not $\vert a+b+c\vert=11$ ? how do you use the fact that $a\gt0$ ? if I may ask?

Comment: @dmtri, If $a+b+c=-11$, then $a=-1<0$.

Comment: I still do not see why if $a+b+c$ is negative then $a$ should be negative too....Can you a bit explain that in your answer, please?